# return data from different table sql to html

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My users have pages:

- user favorites
- users image

I try to do a page "everything" which will get data from 2 sql tables (already have sql code) to one html page ordering all by date. Problem is that "user image" have one html structure and "user favorites" another. Many website have such pages where is output different data in different html structure from different tables. Today I first time tried to do this and do not know the correct way.

My tables:

**users**

- id
- username

**images**

- id
- user_id
- image
- description
- date <--- uplaod date

**user_favorites**

- id
- user_id  <---user id who like image
- image_id     <---id of liked image
- date         <---date when image was clicked "liked"

I get user images with this sql

```
function users_pictures($user_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT username as user, p.image as user_image, i.image, i.id as image_id, i.description as text, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.date) as image_date, COALESCE ( imgcount.cnt, 0 ) as comments
            FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN images i ON i.user_id = u.id
            LEFT JOIN images p ON p.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where u.id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM commentaries GROUP BY image_id  ) imgcount ON i.id = imgcount.image_id
            WHERE i.user_id = ?
            ORDER BY i.date DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $user_id);

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I get all users image and user current image - avatar (last upload image is user avatar)

return example :

```
[images_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user] => 8888
                [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/24/24_0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
                [image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/224/224_0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
                [image_id] => 4
                [text] => 
                [image_date] => 50 minutes
                [comments] => 0
                [user_first_image] => 1
            )

    )
```

User favorite table is :

```
function users_favorites_list($user_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT
                    u.username as user, 
                    p.image as user_image,
                    fav.id as favorite_id, 
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fav.date) as favorite_date, 
                    i.id as images_id,
                    i.image,
                    i.description as text,
                    u2.username as favorite_user,
                    t.image as favorite_user_image

            FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN user_favorites fav ON fav.user_id = u.id
            LEFT JOIN user_follow f ON f.follow_id = fav.user_id
            LEFT JOIN images i ON i.id = fav.image_id
            LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = i.user_id
            LEFT JOIN images p ON p.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where fav.user_id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
            LEFT JOIN images t ON t.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where u2.id = b.user_id ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
            WHERE fav.user_id = ?
            GROUP BY fav.id
            ORDER BY fav.date DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user_id, $user_id));

    return $query->result_array();        
}
```

return example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => 8888
            [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/24/24_0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
            [favorite_id] => 5
            [favorite_date] => 18 minutes ago
            [images_id] => 2
            [image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/100/100_flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
            [text] => 3
            [favorite_user] => 6666
            [favorite_user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/24/24_flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => 8888
            [user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/24/24_0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
            [favorite_id] => 2
            [favorite_date] => 1 week ago
            [images_id] => 4
            [image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/100/100_0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
            [text] => 
            [favorite_user] => 8888
            [favorite_user_image] => http://127.0.0.1/auth_system_1/upload_images/24/24_0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
        )

)
```

:

![My html structure where I try to return data from 2 sql][1]

I need select user activities from 2 table in one page with different html structures (example see image) . I think many peole do it. Please tell me how to do this?

```
[everything_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user] => 8888
                [user_image] => 0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
                [favorite_id] => 5
                [favorite_date] => 1328565406
                [images_id] => 2
                [image] => flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
                [text] => 3
                [favorite_user] => 6666
                [favorite_user_image] => flw3utn9igiqh7dtt2o61ydf8_174.jpeg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user] => 8888
                [user_image] => 0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
                [favorite_id] => 2
                [favorite_date] => 1327856547
                [images_id] => 4
                [image] => 0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
                [text] => 
                [favorite_user] => 8888
                [favorite_user_image] => 0j1kjjzdv3ez07a0ee4lnmjb7_163.jpeg
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below return what you need?

```
SELECT 
    username as user, 
    p.image as user_image, 
    i.image, 
    i.id as image_id, 
    i.description as text, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.date) as image_date, 
    COALESCE ( imgcount.cnt, 0 ) as comments,
    fav.id as favorite_id,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fav.date) as favorite_date,
    u2.username as favorite_user,
    t.image as favorite_user_image
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_favorites fav ON fav.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN user_follow f ON f.follow_id = fav.user_id
LEFT JOIN images i ON i.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = i.user_id
LEFT JOIN images p ON p.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where u.id = b.user_id     ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT image_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM commentaries GROUP BY image_id  )     imgcount ON i.id = imgcount.image_id
LEFT JOIN images t ON t.id = (SELECT b.id FROM images AS b where u2.id = b.user_id     ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE u.user_id = ?
GROUP BY fav.id
ORDER BY i.date DESC
```

Comment: why do I need a limit? I have 3 pages ... 1) user iamge page 2) use favorites page 3) everything . SQL presented here is from 1 and 2 ... how to do and get data from both table and output to page "everything" with different html structure I do not know

Comment: You said 'I need select 3 items (1 from "images" table and 2 from "user_favorites")'. So 1 record from one table and two of the other. This is why you can use LIMIT or you will query all the data from tables without need that.

Comment: ma table have 1 and 2 records

Comment: Ok, but in fact you need all the data of images joined with user_favorites, is that?

Comment: yes. Making one big sql it is problem but not so big as foreach all activities images, favorites images with their html

Comment: I have made query, result is in my topic and trying to get data back with foreach it add to images and two favourites (rows) but I need 1 and 2 not 2 and 2 how to solve this problem ? any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's because the two rows in the favorites. You will need to check if the image id changed between the array results (create a variable to control, that always will have the id of the previous record).

Comment: can you show a small example ? do not understand how to check it. You mean foreach array for [images_id]?